# Redirect all IP but mine + protect with password

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, password-protection

I've a live website and due to maintenance I want to redirect all IP but mine and another one. I want also that every PC from the two enabled IP has to login to see the website. How can I have both things working at the same time?

To redirect all IP I'll add this to.htacces:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^1.2.3.4
RewriteRule .* http://www.anothersite.com [R=302,L]
```

Source: http://kb.siteground.com/how_to_redirect_all_visitors_except_your_ip_to_another_site/

But how can I protect everything also with password, in a way that users IP are redirected to anothersite.com? Also, how can I allow multiple IP? Add them with commas?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a workaround like this

```
SetEnvIfNoCase REMOTE_ADDR "^(?:x\.x\.x\.x|x\.x\.x\.x)$" GET_AUTH=1

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:GET_AUTH} !1
RewriteRule ^ - [R=503,L]

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Forbidden"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Satisfy any
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=GET_AUTH
```

This code will redirect any other IP but yours and the other one (with a HTTP 503 error: maintenance specific and google friendly).

Otherwise, you have the authentication process.